# Extract hours from SQL datetime format?

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have a dataset like this:

```
State  image_datetime
WY      08/21/2017 
        18:02:20
KY      08/21/2017
        17:36:23
IL      08/21/2017
        18:23:04
KY      08/21/2017 
        18:23:04.....
```

I want to extract only the hours part from the image_datetime column, so that the output looks like this:

```
State    image_datetime
WY         18
KY         17
IL         18
KY         18
```

Comment: Isn't `HOUR(image_datetime)` MySQL?

Comment: HOUR function only works if the format is `YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS`.. you need to use DATE_FORMAT or STR_TO_DATE to format to a correct datetime format.

Comment: What is the type of `image_datetime`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos datetime

Comment: If the datatype is datetime you should be able to use function HOUR()

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . No.  `HOUR()` works if the value is stored (properly) as a `datetime` or if another representation can be converted to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming image_datetime is a "datetime" type of attribute, please just use Hour(datetime) function like:

```
SELECT State, HOUR(image_datetime)
FROM table
```

Comment: you are very welcome. I'd appreciate if you may select the answer as correct answer by clicking the tick on the left. Have a good day @user517696